# Issue with Azure Emulator and SQLLOCALDB

Tags: sql-server-2008, azure, azure-compute-emulator

When in try to start Azure Storage Emulator I get the following error.

> Caught exception while probing for SQL endpoint. A network-related or
> instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
> SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify
> that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to
> allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26
>
> - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified) Number of Sql Errors Reported: 1 Sql Error: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: A
>   network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing
>   a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not
>   accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL
>   Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)

All the Components have been correctly installed .
Kindly Help
Thanx

Answer (score 10):

I managed to fix it by deleting and creating my LocalDb instance. In my case it happened because I installed Azure SDK 2.2 over version 2.1.

The step-by-step to fix it:

- Run `sqllocaldb i` to get your instance name:

```
     C:\Users\myUser>sqllocaldb i
     v11.0
```

- Stop LocalDB instance:

```
    C:\Users\myUser>sqllocaldb p v11.0
    LocalDB instance "v11.0" stopped.
```

- Delete your LocalDB instance:

```
    C:\Users\myUser>sqllocaldb d v11.0
    LocalDB instance "v11.0" deleted.
```

- Create your LocalDB instance with the same name:

```
    C:\Users\myUser>sqllocaldb c v11.0
    LocalDB instance "v11.0" created with version 11.0.
```

- Delete database files to allow emulator to recreate db files

```
   C:\Users\myUser\DevelopmentStorageDb22.mdf
   C:\Users\myUser\DevelopmentStorageDb22_log.ldf
```

That should fix your issues.

Answer (score 1):

Might be a little late to the party here, but I've seen this happen if you clear out or remove items in your "*C:\Users[USER_NAME]\AppData\Local\Temp*" folder.

At the time of writing this, **Azurite** is the replacement for "**azure storage emulator**". In my case, I was able to simply follow the steps here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azurite?tabs=npm#install-azurite to get it installed, and you should be good to go after that.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your windows account under which you logged in is not sysadmin in sqlexpress instance. Normally emulator uses database within sqlexpress with windows authentication.

Answer (score 0):

The first time you run the Windows Azure storage emulator, an initialization process runs to configure the environment. By default, the initialization process creates a database in SQL Express LocalDB. So, please make sure that your SQLExpress service is running and your login have sufficient rights to use the database within SQLExpress. 
If you want to make use of a local instance of an SQL Server to be used by Storage Emulator follow steps listed at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg433134.aspx.

HTH
Sameer

Comment: The link is broken

Answer (score 0):

What i am suspecting is that your LocalDB configuration with emulator is somehow corrupted or misconfigured.

Please follow the blog below to see if you can verify LocalDB instance is ready/working and it is used by Emulator:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2012/07/10/windows-azure-sdk-1-7-storage-emulator-and-localdb.aspx

If you still have problem the easiest method would be to uninstall SDK 1.7 completely and re-install which will fix any issue with your configuration rather the finding the problem and try to fix which could take longer.

Comment: The link is broken

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a similar message:

Probing SQL Instance: 'localhost\SQLExpress'.
Caught exception while probing for SQL endpoint. A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
Number of SqlErrors Reported: 1
SqlError: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
No available SQL Instance was found.
One or more initialization actions have failed. Resolve these errors before attempting to run the storage emulator again.
Error: No available SQL Instance was found.

For me the problem was due to the fact that I was not running with administrator privileges.